# .htaccess redirect if containing a substring

Tags: .htaccess

I need to create an .htaccess file that:

if url contains "chat.swf", then redirect to "chat.php"

I tried with

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} chat\.swf
RewriteRule .* chat.php [R=301,L]
```

But it seems bad

Any idea ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^.*\chat.swf$ /chat.php [R=301,L]
```

Comment: tried this and does not work

My other .htaccess rule works normally

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
RewriteRule .* http://www.mysite.com/ [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0):

Cear your browser cache & restart then try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule chat\.swf /chat.php [R=301,L,NC]
```

If for some reason this doesn't work, post your complete .htaccess in your question.